# TypeError: _fs.default.existsSync winston is not a function when using react

Tags: javascript, express, fs, winston

im getting the following error when using my module within a react.

My module allows you to log ajax calls, to a log file. It works on npm start on my module, but doesn't work on react client side.

I get the following error.

> TypeError: _fs.default.existsSync is not a function
>
> // Create the log directory if it does not exist   25 |
>
> > 26 | if (!_fs["default"].existsSync(logDir)) {   27 |   _fs["default"].mkdirSync(logDir);   28 | }   29 |

**index.js**

```
// Create the log directory if it does not exist
if (!fs.existsSync(logDir)) {
  fs.mkdirSync(logDir);
}

const filename = path.join(logDir, 'stuff.json');


/**
 * Makes axios call
 * @param {params} object
 *
*/
let logger = [];



const ourLogger = createLogger({
    level: 'info',
    format: format.json(),
    defaultMeta: { service: 'user-service' },
    transports: [
      //
      // - Write to all logs with level `info` and below to `combined.log` 
      // - Write all logs error (and below) to `error.log`.
      //
      new transports.File({ filename })
    ]
});
```

Comment: Why would it work in a React application? React is client-side, and `fs` is a Node module, it runs in NodeJS, server-side. Browsers will never allow javascript to access the file system. It's a _very_ good thing that it doesn't work in React (or in a browser in general). Any website would be able to read and delete the content of your hard disk. And you don't want that to happen.

Comment: oh i see so their is no other solution ? thanks for this

Comment: So how would one go about logging react errors to a file ?

Comment: Logging client-side error to a file? I don't think it's directly possible. The only way I can see to do this would be to catch the errors and send them to your server (using a regular Ajax call) so it can write them in a file.

Comment: @JeremyThille Yeah how would you go about doing that ? do you have a reference or a recommended library that would be able to do that

Comment: A library? No, what for? Just catch your errors with a `try-catch` block and send them to your back end as regular data. Then, the back-end can write that to a file (or even better, to a database, so it can be queried)

Comment: what if you're trying to make a node module that handles this already ? its already built in. Would it be possible to achieve that ?

Comment: What do you mean, of course it's possible to achieve that. Where exactly are you stuck? Make an attempt, and if you're stuck somewhere, Stackoverflow may be able to help you.